# Webpack - how do I make compiled functions available in HTML documents?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I've got a webpack script

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (env, options) => ({
  entry: "./clickscape.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js'),
    filename: 'clickscape-bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
})
```

that generates a bundle. Inside my `clickscape.js`, there are functions that I want to be able to access in the HTML page in which the bundle is loaded, i.e.:

```
<script src="http://localhost:4000/js/clickscape-bundle.js"></script>
<script>do_something_clickscape_dot_js()</script>
```

It seems that because webpack obfuscates all the code it compiles, it's not obvious what to call outside it.

What do I need to do to make my calls work?

Comment: It's not a global. You could make it a global by defining it as `window.do_something_clickscape_dot_js = () => {// your code}`. Is there any reason not to call it within your bundle where it is in scope?

Comment: Are you creating a library or is it part of an application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless such a variable is global, you can't. Which generally is a good thing as it prevents name collisions between your own variables and those of other (external) scripts.

> Inside my clickscape.js, there are functions that I want to be able to
>   access in the HTML page in which the bundle is loaded (...)

If you necessarily want to access them in the HTML page, you could make them global in `./clickscape.js`:

```js
window.do_something_clickscape_dot_js = function() {
    // your code
}
```

Now `do_something_clickscape_dot_js()` works in your HTML page. But why not call it directly in `./clickscape.js`?

```js
const do_something_clickscape_dot_js = () => {
    // do something here
}

/*
 * calling the function in this file has same effect as calling it
 * in script tag in the HTML page
 */
do_something_clickscape_dot_js();
```

I can't think of a use case where you necessarily want to call it in the HTML page, but if you want to: go for a global.